# RxJava style LiveData TestObserver and test extension fails with NullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-livedata

I created a `TestObserver` class like RxJava counterpart and LiveData extension function to test multiple values of LiveData, such as states like `LOADING` and as result of the action `ERROR` or `SUCCESS`.

```
class TestObserver<T>(private val liveData: LiveData<T>) : Observer<T> {

    init {
        liveData.observeForever(this)
    }

    private val testValues = mutableListOf<T>()

    override fun onChanged(t: T) {
        if (t != null) testValues.add(t)
    }

    fun testAssertNoValues(): TestObserver<T> {
        if (testValues.isNotEmpty()) throw AssertionException("Assertion error with actual size ${testValues.size}")
        return this
    }

    fun testAssertValueCount(count: Int): TestObserver<T> {
        if (count < 0) throw AssertionException("Assert count cannot be smaller than zero")
        if (count != testValues.size) throw AssertionException("Assertion error with expected $count while actual ${testValues.size}")
        return this
    }

    fun assertValues(vararg predicates: T): TestObserver<T> {
        predicates.forEach { predicate ->
            testValues.forEach { testValue ->
                if (predicate != testValue) throw  Exception("Assertion error")
            }
        }
        return this
    }

    fun assertValues(predicate: List<T>.() -> Boolean): TestObserver<T> {
        testValues.predicate()
        return this
    }

    fun values(predicate: List<T>.() -> Unit): TestObserver<T> {
        testValues.predicate()
        return this
    }

    fun values(): List<T> {
        return testValues
    }


    fun dispose() {
        testValues.clear()
        liveData.removeObserver(this)
    }
}


fun <T> LiveData<T>.test(): TestObserver<T> {

    val testObserver = TestObserver(this)

    observeForever(testObserver)

    return testObserver
}

class AssertionException(message: String) : Exception(message)
```

And using this on a sample test to check if it works

```
  @Test
    fun test() = testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {

        val myTestData = MutableLiveData<Int>()
        myTestData.value = 1
        myTestData.value = 2
        myTestData.value = 3

        myTestData.test().values {

            this.forEach {
                println(" Test numbers: $it")
            }
        }

    }
```

But mutableList is null i wonder why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `liveData.removeObserver(this)` before observing it solved the issue. And made some changes on full implmentation.

```
/**
 * RxJava style [Observer] for [LiveData] to test multiple values or states in container.
 *
 * This class is useful for testing view or action states or order of states if you are using
 * stateful machine.
 *
 * * Use with `InstantTaskExecutorRule` or a similar mechanism to execute tasks synchronously.
 *
 */

class LiveDataTestObserver<T> constructor(
    private val liveData: LiveData<T>
) : Observer<T> {

    init {
        liveData.observeForever(this)
    }

    private val testValues = mutableListOf<T>()

    override fun onChanged(t: T) {
        if (t != null) testValues.add(t)
    }

    fun assertNoValues(): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {
        if (testValues.isNotEmpty()) throw AssertionError(
            "Assertion error with actual size ${testValues.size}"
        )
        return this
    }

    fun assertValueCount(count: Int): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {
        if (count < 0) throw AssertionError(
            "Assertion error! value count cannot be smaller than zero"
        )
        if (count != testValues.size) throw AssertionError(
            "Assertion error! with expected $count while actual ${testValues.size}"
        )
        return this
    }

    fun assertValues(vararg predicates: T): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {
        if (!testValues.containsAll(predicates.asList())) throw AssertionError("Assertion error!")
        return this
    }

    fun assertValues(predicate: (List<T>) -> Boolean): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {
        predicate(testValues)
        return this
    }

    fun values(predicate: (List<T>) -> Unit): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {
        predicate(testValues)
        return this
    }

    fun values(): List<T> {
        return testValues
    }

    /**
     * Removes this observer from the [LiveData] which was observing
     */
    fun dispose() {
        liveData.removeObserver(this)
    }

    /**
     * Clears data available in this observer and removes this observer from the [LiveData] which was observing
     */
    fun clear() {
        testValues.clear()
        dispose()
    }
}

fun <T> LiveData<T>.test(): LiveDataTestObserver<T> {

    val testObserver = LiveDataTestObserver(this)

    // Remove this testObserver that is added in init block of TestObserver, and clears previous data
    testObserver.clear()
    observeForever(testObserver)

    return testObserver
}
```